Proof of dimension of Linear ODE Solution Space
If I have a linear ODE of the form $a_n(t)y^{(n)}...+a_0(t)y=0$, in the case where the coefficient functions are constant, it is easy to see why the solution space is $N$ dimensional. But if these coefficient functions are not constant, can someone provide a full proof that the space of solutions is spanned by $N$ fundamental solutions? I understand the intuition but in most textbooks it's provided without proof.
